# $U$ an open neighbourhood of the origin $\Rightarrow$ then there is an open neighbourhood $N$ of the origin s.t $\alpha N \subset U.$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

First of all I have asked this question one time before here:

[$U$ open neighbourhood of the origin. Then there is an open neighbourhood $N$ of the origin st $\alpha N \subset U$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2039084/u-open-neighbourhood-of-the-origin-then-there-is-an-open-neighbourhood-n-of)

But I was wondering if there might be another way to solve, using the following:

$(V,T)$ topological vector space over $\mathbb{F}$.

$U$ is an open neighbourhood of the origin, then there exists a balanced neighbourhood $W$ s.t $W \subset U$. Since $W$ is balanced then $\alpha W \subset W$ $\forall \alpha \in \mathbb{F} :  |\alpha | \leq 1$. My question now is, can one prove that $\alpha W$ is an open neighbourhood aswell?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to show
$ W \in \mathcal{T} \Rightarrow \alpha W \in \mathcal{T}$ for $\alpha \neq 0$ then there is not much to do, because you started with a topological vectorspace $(V,\mathcal{T})$.

You can easily show that $\phi_\alpha: V \to V,\; x \mapsto \alpha x$ is a homeomorphism.
This results from an axiom of the topological vectorspace and the fact that $\phi_{\frac{1}{\alpha}}$ is the inverse of $\phi_\alpha$
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_vector_space#Definition

However this gives you a circular argument because you want to show that there is a balanced neighborhood $N$ of $U$ by using that you already have one ($W$).